# 500 error when using github site-maven-plugin to publish directory to gh-pages

Tags: maven, github

I'm trying to use the github site plugin to copy a directory to my gh-pages branch on github.  I'm getting a 500 error whenever I try, though.

Here's my build configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
            <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <message>Creating site for ${project.version}</message>
                <branch>gh-pages</branch>
                <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <repositoryName>greenDAO</repositoryName>
                <repositoryOwner>emmby</repositoryOwner>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Here's the output of `mvn ghSite:site`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DaoCore 1.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- site-maven-plugin:0.7:site (default-cli) @ greendao ---
[INFO] Creating 12 blobs
[INFO] Creating tree with 13 blob entries
[INFO] Creating commit with SHA-1: 656a23ffd7d898c2d45a107ee4f8f2d8ee86706e
[INFO] Creating reference gh-pages starting at commit 656a23ffd7d898c2d45a107ee4f8f2d8ee86706e
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.608s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 22 22:25:21 MST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.7:site (default-cli) on project greendao: Error creating reference: Server Error (500) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

You can find the full output of `mvn -X ghSite:site` [here](https://gist.github.com/4364071).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

(My authentication credentials are in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file and appear to be correct, since the push fails with an authentication error if I comment them out.)

Comment: If I check the doc (https://github.com/github/maven-plugins), there is a github.global.server property. Did you set it?

Comment: Also, add the -X flag (debug). Maybe you'll find out something more.

Comment: Yes, github.global.server property is set.  I have the output of -X as well, but it didn't seem to include much additional info.  I can add it if it would be helpful

Comment: In your log I see ... 'greendao', but repositoryName is 'greenDAO'. That's normal?

Comment: I think that's fine?  the local filesystem and maven artifacts are named greendao, but the github repo is greenDAO: https://github.com/emmby/greenDAO

Comment: Maybe try the dryRun option and see if it still fails

Comment: Also speficy an execution: <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>site</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>site</phase>
        </execution>

Comment: dryRun works fine.  executions don't change anything

Comment: Are you sure your branch is correct? Shouldnt it be 'refs/heads/gh-pages' (default)

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  Stick it in an answer and I'll mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your branch is incorrect:

```
<branch>gh-pages</branch>
```

Remove it and use the default.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this maven plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-scm-publish-plugin/various-tips.html ?